# Two similar apps share a DB. Ran a migration on one. Cannot run the same migration on the second one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I'm using Heroku and have two apps that share the same PG database. The second one is an enhanced version of the first one and I am trying to transition away from the first to the second gradually. But in the meantime I have to keep both running. Here's what I did:

1. I cloned App #1 into App #2, and made some refinements to App #2.
2. From App #1, I ran a migration to add index (added user_id index on memberships table). It worked fine.
3. From App #2, I added the same migration and tried to run it. This time it threw the following error because the index already exists from the previous migration on the same table:

> > Migrating to AddIndexToMemberships (20141110055825)
> >     ==  AddIndexToMemberships: migrating ==========================================
> >
> > -- add_index(:memberships, :user_id)
> >
> > rake aborted!
> >     StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
> >
> > Index name 'index_memberships_on_user_id' on table 'memberships' already exists/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:815:in `add_index_options'

Although I have to keep App #1 running for a while, I will be mostly maintaining App #2 from now on. In this case what is the right way to resolve this issue?

Comment: If they share the same database? The first time you run migration would also have affected the second website.

Comment: Yes of course, it's the same DB. But I was asking about how to deal with the migration files. App #1 and App #2 both have the same add_index commands, so when I try to run migration from App #2 it fails. I can't just get rid of the add_index migration lines from App #2 code because I still want to keep track on this side as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two migrations add index to the same tables, you can change the second application's migration name to have the same timestamp as the first.